# Unable to unzip file

Tags: command-line, locale, unzip

trying to unzip a file so im trying the following command 
Sorry im really quite new to linux

btw this is Ubuntu server latest release.

```
user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$ ls
rtk.zip
user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$ sudo unzip rtk.zip
sudo: unzip: command not found
user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$
```

When I try without sudo I get this

```
user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$ unzip rtk.zip
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.2.3 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
Exception information:

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, incrash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Thanks in advace

EDIT - The zip file I had turned out to be corrupt.

Comment: Are you sure you have `unzip` installed? If not, `sudo apt-get install unzip`

Comment: Just installed and got this back when unzipping. user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$ unzip rtk.zip
Archive:  rtk.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of rtk.zip or
        rtk.zip.zip, and cannot find rtk.zip.ZIP, period.
user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$

Comment: @Valkyrie0512, the End-of-central-directory thing means the zip is invalid. Redownload it and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 57):

You probably need to install `unzip`

```
sudo apt-get install zip unzip
```

as far as your error message, yes you should probably file a bug report on that one.

["How do I report a bug?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: No luck, Received this. user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$ unzip rtk.zip
Archive:  rtk.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of rtk.zip or
        rtk.zip.zip, and cannot find rtk.zip.ZIP, period.
user@serverubuntu:~/minecraft/server$

Comment: @Valkyrie0512 That means either the file isn't a zip file after all despite its name, or the file is corrupted (possibly truncated). What does `file rtk.zip` show? Can you verify the size of the zip file?

Comment: or that the archive was corrupt.

Comment: Ahh my bad, turns out the fil is courrupted

Comment: For CentOs, this worked: yum install zip unzip

Comment: Thanks. THis worked. You can also run `sud apt install unzip`